# Android: From database to listview, doens't show nothing

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple database, with `_id` column and `createdOn` column.

Trying to print a listView, but my code doesn't show nothing (neither I've errors, also, in LOG I have correctly my values).

Thank you for your help.

**EventActivity.java**

```
[...]

private void getEvent(){
        db = new DBManager(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.query();
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_activity,
                cursor,
                new String[] { "createdOn" },
                new int[] { R.id.singleDate });

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDate1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, cursor.getLong(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1));
            // here I have all my entries in log
        }
```

**list_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDate1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/singleDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is in creating the adapter

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
    R.layout.list_row, // that's the layout to inflate for each row
    cursor,
    new String[] { "createdOn" }, // those are the cursor columns
    new int[] { R.id.singleDate }); // those are the layout views
                                    // to match to the cursor columns
```

Comment: Sorry, I make a mistake on column name, see my edited question. Thank you and sorry again...

Comment: I just edited my answer. You still have the wrong layout. `R.layout.list_activity` instead of `R.layout.list_row`